# Snap.svg circular path animation returning path data error of NaN

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hunterleaman/aha24p0h/)

I'm using snap.svg to create a circle button with a border that winds around the button on hover and unwinds on mouseout but I had to hack it together a bit.

The original implementation that I used as a template used a step function as the setter function in Snap.animate but I ran into an issue where the mouseout event would leave a residual block from the path, so I added "-1" from the second "step" variable (line 55).

```
path: Snap.path.getSubpath(loop, 0, step-1)
```

---

Relevent section of js

```
var hoverbpath =  s.path({
  path: Snap.path.getSubpath(loop, 0, 0),
  stroke: "#000",
  fillOpacity: 0,
  strokeWidth: 0,
  strokeLinecap: "square"
});

ctabtn.hover(function(e){
  Snap.animate(0, loopLength,
    function(step){
      hoverbpath.attr({
      path: Snap.path.getSubpath(loop, 0, step),
      strokeWidth: 11
    });
  }, 250, mina.easeIn);
ctabtn.attr({fill: "l(0, 0, 1, 1)#000-#333"});
});

hoverbpath.mouseout(function(e){
  Snap.animate(loopLength, 0,
    function(step){
      hoverbpath.attr({
      path: Snap.path.getSubpath(loop, 0, step-1),
      strokeWidth: 11
    });
  }, 250, mina.easeOut);
ctabtn.attr({fill: "l(0, 0, 1, 1)#333-#000"});
});
```

It's working fine but it's returning an error every mouseout event: "Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="M74.7,5.2CNaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN"e @ snap.svg-min.js:18"

I'd like to know if the implementation of the button and animation could be optimized or, if not, then how to fix the error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing code from [this example](http://codepen.io/JRGould/pen/dkHhw), which simply adds a callback to the end of the `mouseout` handler to set the path to `strokeWidth=0`. So it doesn't remove that last little piece, it just hides it, which I think is fine.

First step: Remove the `step-1` hack you added, just use `step` in both handlers. Then adjust your JS like so:

```
hoverbpath.mouseout(function(e){
  Snap.animate(loopLength, 0,
    function(step){
      hoverbpath.attr({
        path: Snap.path.getSubpath(loop, 0, step),
        strokeWidth: 11
      });
    }, 250, mina.easeOut, function() {
      hoverbpath.attr({
        path: Snap.path.getSubpath(loop, 0, 0),
        strokeWidth: 0
      });
    });
ctabtn.attr({fill: "l(0, 0, 1, 1)#333-#000"});
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aha24p0h/1/